# Having problems with OnBecameVisible (sees through walls and is visible on scene view)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, renderer

I'm trying to make a script that has an enemy chase the player only if the enemy is viewable by the player camera and the player hits the space key. I've been trying to use render.isVisible but run in to two MAJOR problems:

1. isVisible is enabled even if the enemy is visible in the scene view, making testing impossible.
2. isVisible works through walls, so if the player is looking at a wall and the enemy is behind it, it still registers as isVisible.

Please help I'm losing my mind. Thank you!

```
public NavMeshAgent enemy;
public Transform player;

Renderer m_Renderer;

private void Start()
{
    m_Renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}

private void OnBecomeInvisible()
{
    enabled = false;
}

void OnBecameVisible()
{
    enabled = true;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && m_Renderer.isVisible)
    {
        Debug.Log("is visible");

        enemy.SetDestination(player.position);
    }

}

private void Update()
{
        OnBecameVisible();
}
```

I'm honestly not sure what to try, thank you so much for any help!

Answer (score 2):

IsVisible is really not designed for that usage.  It just means object is being rendered by any camera.  See the documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-isVisible.html

To determine whether something is actually visible from one entity by another, you typically have to do a frustum check followed by one or more raycasts to determine whether the target is blocked.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I'll look more into that. I'm hella new so I don't know too much about raycasts or frustum checks.